# Specify source IP connecting to Mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a webserver with multiple IP addresses.
Whenver I attempt to connect to a remote DB server using perl DBI ( or even php ) the source IP is the primary IP address of the machine

How can I change the source IP address.
One of the secondary IP addresses is alone allowed to connect to the DB.

Comment: All out-bound requests are made via the primary IP address bound to `eth0`, as the other IPs are really aliases of that IP address most of the time. If you want to force a specific source address to be used for specific destinations, you can do it with a SNAT rule, but I imagine you will get alot more help on this subject on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish you showed me how you are trying to connect, I mean the Code, but Basically what you do in php, Define the Host as:

```
$hostname=$hostip;//$hostipaddress is supposed to be the Static Ip address of your Webserver,
```

If the problem persists, please Define your host Ip address using the parameters and Call it everytime you want to use it, so that it will be taking the current time Ipaddress. I hope that helps you.